# React router catching webapi routes

Tags: .net, reactjs, .net-core, react-router, asp.net-core-webapi

.NET Core 3.1 web application with react 16.12.0.

**Problem**

Newbie at react... when I fetch 'api/checksheet/types' it gets caught by '/checksheet/:checkSheetTypeId' and it attempts to load the component declared for that route.

How do I eliminate the conflict between front end and server side routes?

**Server side, 2 endpoints**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CheckSheetController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/checksheet/types
    [HttpGet]
    public IList Types()
    {
    }

    // GET: api/checksheet/{id}
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public Dto Get(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
<Layout>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/checksheet/add' component={AddChecksheet} />
        <Route path='/checksheet/:checkSheetTypeId' component={TasksPage} />
    </Switch>
</Layout>
```

**Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class NavMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { types: [], loading: true };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getTypes();
    }

    async getTypes() {
        const response = await fetch('api/checksheet/types');
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ types: data, loading: false });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coming to think about, I can solve this by following the RESTful API naming conventions, so that CheckSheetController is pluralised, then making my endpoint calls /api/checksheets/{id}

Though there must be another solution....